# How did craniates evolve?

Tags: evolution, zoology, invertebrates

Looking at most chordate phylogenetic trees, it seems that we usually have something like this:

```
  ,================= Lancelets    
 =| ,=============== Tunicates
  \_|
    \_______________ Craniates
```

So, my question is, **what do we think the common ancestor of tunicates and craniates looked like?** Did both clades evolve from a lancelet-like ancestor, with the tunicates becoming sessile after the divergence, or are craniates descended from a tunicate-like ancestor?